# Зачем нужны функциональные интерфейсы?

Tags: java, интерфейс

В чем их преимущество? Где их используют? Чем они отличаются от 'просто' интерфейса с одним методом? Есть примеры использования функциональных интерфейсов(насколько я знаю - Runnable)?
Почему они именно функциональные, т.е. они как-то связаны с функциональным программированием?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Любой интерфейс с одним методом называется функциональный. Никаких дополнительных преимуществ или отличий у них нет. Так называются они потому, что представляют функцию.

Comment: Что значит представляют функцию?

Comment: функциональный интерфейс позволяет использовать лямбда выражения, т.к. к них не указывается какой именно метод вызывается, то компилятор способен понять что среди одного метода именно его и нужно вызвать.

Comment: В Java нет функций. Всё _поведение_ располагается в методах. Но для колбэков, например, нужно только поведение, но не состояние, поэтому объект "оборачивающий" метод бесполезен. Интерфейс с одним методом - это способ эмулировать функцию в Java.

Comment: @Maxim лямбды на уровне байткода - это просто прокси-классы, реализующие интерфейс с одним методом. Который так же легко можно назвать не функциональным, а SAM-интерфейсом. То есть никаких технических особенностей нет, это просто определение.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev так как именно он эмулирует функцию? Как run в Runnable?

Comment: Функция - это просто участок кода. Чаще всего именованный. Интерфейс с одним объявленным методом позволяет вам объявить анонимный класс с одним методом, что наиболее близко к функции. Такой вот незатейливый костыль для языка, который был спроектирован только под ООП.

Comment: Проще всего разобраться, взглянув на класс Function и поюзав его функции (Consumer, Function, Predicate etc...)