# Для чего нужны функциональные интерфейсы в Java?

Tags: java, лямбда-выражение

Совсем недавно начал изучать программирование и наткнулся на тему лямбда-выражений. На протяжении изучения никак не мог понять зачем нужны функциональные интерфейсы, если вместо них можно использовать обычную функцию? Пример:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    lol operation = (x,y)->x+y;
    System.out.println(operation.printLol(2,3));
    System.out.println(sum(2,3));

    }
interface lol {
    int printLol(int x, int y);
    }
public static long sum(int x, int y){
    return x+y;
}
```

Так в чем отличие функции от функционального интерфейса? Когда стоит применять функциональный интерфейс, а когда - функцию?

Comment: Смысл в том, чтобы использовать функцию как переменную/аргумент. С обычными функциями такое не прокатит, потому что Java - это не функциональный язык программирования.

Comment: А как же ссылки на методы?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду `::`? Так там же в основе как раз функциональные интерфейсы и лежат.

Comment: А, спасибо большое)

Comment: Передача ссылки на метод фактически лямбду создает. Которая реализует соответствующий функциональный интерфейс.

Comment: @insolor, ссылка на метод [_проще реализуется_](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/878255/), чем лямбда

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Зачем нужны функциональные интерфейсы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/867660/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%8b)

Comment: Я смотрел этот вопрос. В комментариях нет ответа когда стоит применять функциональный интерфейс, а когда - метод.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Существует так называемый *функциональный* подход к программированию, при котором мы можем оперировать методами (функциями) как переменными.

Есть языки программирования, в которые такая возможность встроена непосредственно, на синтаксическом уровне: они называются функциональными. К таким языкам относится, например, **Haskell**.

В языках **C** и **C++** можно использовать ссылки на методы, причём не те, которые в Java (об этом далее), а настоящие ссылки.

В языке же Java нет ни того, ни другого, поэтому функциональное программирование в ней осуществляется посредством функциональных интерфейсов.

Когда мы пишем что-то вроде

```
(car) -> car.getOwner();
```

нам кажется, будто мы действительно объявляем функцию на месте и программируем в функциональном стиле. Но на деле для такой записи создаётся анонимный класс, расширяющий целевой интерфейс и реализующий метод в соответствии с тем, что написано после стрелки.

Упомянутая вами *ссылка на метод* - это просто способ ещё более коротко и изящно записать лямбда-выражение. Например, приведённая выше строка могла бы выглядеть так:

```
Car::getOwner
```

---

Для чего в целом всё это нужно - я думаю, тут можно продолжить пример, строки кода для которого я написал выше. Есть у нас список автомобилей, и нам нужно его преобразовать в список владельцев. К примеру, используя Stream API.

Очень грустно было бы для метода `map()` объявлять отдельный класс, имплементирующий целевой интерфейс и содержащий один простой метод, а потом в методе `map()` создавать объект от него с целью вызова этого самого метода.

Гораздо лучше написать короткую лямбду, а, если ситуация позволяет, то и вовсе ссылку на метод. И пусть это не чистое функциональное программирование, а скорее некая его реализация за счёт ООП, пользоваться этим всё равно удобно.

Использование лямбда-выражений сокращает и упрощает код, а также во многих случаях делает его более читаемым и выразительным.

---

> Когда стоит применять функциональный интерфейс, а когда - функцию?

Лямбда-выражение нужно использовать только в том случае, когда для неёго есть *контекст*: соответствующий функциональный интерфейс. Для примера возьмём всё тот же метод `map()` в Stream API. Этот метод ждёт на вход следующий аргумент:

```
Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper
```

Соответственно, простой метод здесь не применить. Можно либо (зачем-то) создать объект от полноценного отдельного класса, имплементирующего `Function<>`, либо, что более логично, задействовать лямбду.

Во всех остальных случаях используются обычные методы. То есть, лямбда-выражения применяются только тогда, когда в них есть смысл.

Comment: Спасибо, мне теперь понятно как это работает, но ответьте, пожалуйста, на вопрос: "Когда стоит применять функциональный интерфейс, а когда - функцию?"

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за развернутый и понятный ответ))